# Rails 4 planning your app for efficient queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, performance

I am still fairly new to creating rails apps from scratch and would like to know the best way to set them up for efficient queries.

Consider this scenario. You are building a social site that shares books using mysql2 for a database. You start with two models; a **user** and an **author**.  Both need `name` attributes; `first_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name` etc.

Would it be more efficient to create a **name** model where name would be it's own individual table?

Or add name attributes to the individual **user** and **author** where the attributes remain as columns?

Answer (score 2):

First, you might consider implementing this using PostgreSQL - there are many, but performance is one of the reasons.

More, you have to think the system you build should be maintainable. Having a separate table for the name can be a very bad idea. Do you plan to add names for all the models you have in that one name table? Sounds weird. What problem do you think you could solve by doing that?

Instead, I think indexes can help you out  (https://tomafro.net/2009/08/using-indexes-in-rails-index-your-associations) when it comes to retrieving associations.

And I cannot give you more advices on your data model. This depends on the requirements and future intentions. Are you going to query per model and then retrieve associations? Is there going to be sort of a tagging approach to handle synonyms?

Comment: Thank you for the great response! What would the advantage be with using PostgreSQL?  I haven't used it yet so I'm quite unfamiliar with it. 

My main concern is that my intuition felt wrong having the same attributes for different tables. I didn't know if it would later somehow break the DRY principle as well as slow down queries. Once again, this is all intuition as I have no clue how the queries will perform later down the road. 

I'll try using some indexes. It's a perfect time to get more familiar with them!

Comment: The scenario above is a simple example for question's sake. The project I'm working on will be a poll where Users can "agree" or "disagree" with quotes from certain Authors. So i'll be retrieving many different queries but still have to figure out how I'll go about that.  Thank you again btw!